# How to specify certificate's alias name in system property while making a 2way SSL connection?

Tags: ssl, smartcard, cac

I am trying to run a Java client with 2way SSL, which uses CAC card as keystore for the client. I have added the following system property in my client program to make it work and also changed the *java.security* file to add *pcks11* provider.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs11");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

The program works fine and the handshake is done successfully. However, when I have more than one trusted certificate in the CAC card, it takes the default certificate. I want to specify which certificate should be used to do the client auth (maybe by specifying the alias name), but I didn't find any system property to do that.

How can I specify the alias name as a system property, so that the 2way SSL will use it for the client auth?

Is there another way to specify the alias name? For example, when I access the server URL from any browser I would get a certificate selection prompt and the connection is established with the selected certificate.

Answer (score 0):

For choosing a client certificate, the default implementation (`sun.security.ssl.X509KeyManagerImpl`, assuming you're using the Sun JRE) chooses the first certificate that it can use for the request.

PKCS#11 is a slightly specific case. As far as I'm aware, there would only be one private key + certificate chain per slot. If no slot is specified in your PKCS#11 provider configuration, the default one will be 0.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your response. 

In my case, I am using a CAC card which has more than one trusted certificate in it.

My question is to select one particular certificate for handshake. Let me know is there a way to do this.

Comment: What does your PKCS#11 configuration look like?

Comment: In Some forum I got the info that writing a CustomKeyfactory would resolve the issue ,

AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","com.ssl.MySSLSocketFactory");

But I never get a call back to get the key factory or the context in the custom key factory.

Any idea?

Comment: If you're using a PKCS#11 provider, it will most likely be configurable by the `slot` option in your PKCS#11 configuration file (configured with the provider). If you don't provide more details about the config, it's hard to tell... I doubt `axis.socketSecureFactory` is where to choose the cert from the PKCS#11 token.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no specific property in java ssl properties it is better to search for a different existing keymanager implementation which supports this or else write your own custom keymanager so that you can pick the specific certificate with it's alias name.

Thanks,
Sunny.